# Middleware and user - laravel 5

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

How can i assign middleware to user? I just follow the guide on laravel 5.2 but i can't figure... 
I'm able to create middleware ( i have admin middleware)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I'm able to assign middleware to route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('admin/tasks', 'Admin\\TasksController');
});
```

but how can i check if user is admin or not? I just follow the docs on laravel 5.2 for authentication, but i dont know how to access the page only for "admin" middleware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [ENTRUST Laravel package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

> Entrust is a succinct and flexible way to add Role-based Permissions
>   to Laravel 5.

Comment: i try, but is bad, only errors return me on laravel 5.2

BadMethodCallException in Repository.php line 367: This cache store does not support tagging.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1** How to check if user is admin

I think using `session` is a good solution. You can store the user status in the session. And in the `Admin` middleware, you can check if user is admin by `if (session('statut') === 'admin')`.

**Question 2** Page Access of users

- If user is admin, we will pass the request by `return $next($request);`
- If user is not admin, we will redirect to index page or other page
  you want by `return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));`

The following code may help you.

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

    class Admin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (session('statut') === 'admin')
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

    }
```

Comment: thank you man, I'm learning with puople like you, and @Pavel Krasnoperov

Answer (score 1):

I have a small example for you, it very simple

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If you only have guest and admin(who is authenticated in your system) you should do like above. But if you have another roles you will have to attach ACL (for ex https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

Comment: thank you, i just use zizaco with little modification in .env file!